# Unable to Download Images from S3 Bucket in Python/Code has Access Keys already

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

For a project, I need to download some items in my S3 bucket. I have already seen similar posts about this topic; however, I hardcoded my access key ID and secret access key inside the program and am still unable to download them. Python keeps returning the error:

"botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials"

Despite providing my credentials, I am still unable to download. My code is provided below. Can anyone help me correct this?

```
import boto3
import os
"""import sys
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf"""
import nibabel as nib
from boto3.session import Session


aws_access_key_id = '********************'
aws_secret_access_key = '****************************************'
bucket1 = 'adnimcic'
mcic = [[], [], []]
mcicc = [[], [], []]
bucket2 = 'adnimcinc'
mcinc = [[], [], []]
bucket3 = 'adniresults'
results = []
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')


#connecting to S3
session = Session(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket1obj = s3.Bucket(bucket1)
#bucket2obj = s3.Bucket(bucket2)
#'MCIc_Segmented/ADNI_002_S_0729_MR_MP-RAGE_REPEAT_br_raw_20070225105857428_72_S27091_I41585_be_be_pve_2.nii.gz_extracted'
def concatenate(name):
    name = name.split('.')
    name.pop()
    name = name[0] + '.' + name[1]
    name = name.split('/')
    name = name[1]
    return name

def download(bucketname, key):
    path = '/Volumes/LaCie Mac/' + concatenate(key.key)
    s3_client.download_file(bucketname, key.key, path)

for key in bucket1obj.objects.all():
    if 'pve_0' and 'extracted' in key.key:
        mcic[0].append(key)
        download(bucket1, key)
for key in bucket1obj.objects.all():
    if 'pve_1' and 'extracted' in key.key:
        mcic[1].append(key)
        download(bucket1, key)
for key in bucket1obj.objects.all():
    if 'pve_2' and 'extracted' in key.key:
        mcic[2].append(key)
        download(bucket1, key)
```

Comment: Can you show us the IAM or Bucket Policy that you have that grants access to the buckets?

Comment: Side-note: It is recommended that you _never_ put access credentials in your code. Instead, create a credentials file using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws configure` command. Your code will then automatically locate the credentials.

Comment: @JamieStarke I made the buckets public in order to perhaps bypass the need for credentials. The data in them isn't personal or sensitive at all; unless someone wants to mess with my medical imaging project which uses publicly available data, it does not matter who has access.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code, you have two different **S3** objects, `s3_client` and `s3`:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

...

session = Session(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
s3 = session.resource('s3')

...

def download(bucketname, key):
    path = '/Volumes/LaCie Mac/' + concatenate(key.key)
    s3_client.download_file(bucketname, key.key, path)
```

```

Looking at your code, it looks like you use your `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` on your `session` object which you use on your `s3` resource as expected, but you don't use the session on the `s3_client`.

If I understand your problem correctly, you should be able to resolve this issue by creating the client from your session, like:

```
session = Session(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
s3 = session.resource('s3')
s3_client = session.client('s3')
```